# Vitamio 5 Notification from Google Play

Tags: vitamio

I already update my project to vitamio 5 from: https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/ but I can't update my app in google play they still say that my app have vulnerabilities, can someone help me wit this issue please; thanks.

This is the notification from google play:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected , with package name , for violating our Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users.
>
> Below is the list of vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>   Vulnerability APK Version(s)
>   Vitamio
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in Vitamio v.5.0 and higher. To confirm the vulnerability, check to see if your SDK includes `libs/armeabi-v7a/libvinit.so` or `libs/armeabi/libvinit.so`. If either file is present, the SDK needs to be upgraded.
>
> You can find more information and next steps in this Google Help Center article.
>   4
>
> To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.
>
> While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out to our policy support team through the Google Play Developer Help Center.
>
> Best,
>   The Google Play Team

Comment: We need the full sdk to continue this outdated project. =(